# Potentiometer anchor points in Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I need to create a potentiometer with a tap point, as shown as the (american) potentiometer on page 9 of the Circuitikz manual. Is the tap an accessible anchor point to connect other parts of the circuit to (in a similar way to opamp.+, opamp._ points)? If not, is the only way to create a tap to draw an ordinary resistor and manually add a tap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, name the potentiometer (using the `n` key) and use the `wiper` anchor; for example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
  (0,0) to[american potentiometer,n=mypot] ++(2,0)
  (mypot.wiper) to[short,-o] ++(2,0)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. That is exactly what I was after. Many thanks.